# Handling model in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement my first Spring MVC controller, following Spring documentation, some tutorials and the "Spring in Action" book.

Now I have a doubt: implementing the controller methods I find differences in handling the model.
Sometimes they use a `Map<String, Object>`, a `Model` object or else a `ModelAndView` object.

Which is the difference among using an object or another?
Which is the reason for choosing one instead of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModelAndView, contains the model, and the name of the view. ModelMap, in contract, only contains information about the model.

So with model and view you can explicity set the view name.

If you just set up the model and return a string in your controller , the view name is inferred from the request uri.

Answer (score 0):

Spring docs: 'In the normal case, a ModelAndView instance consists of a view name and a model Map, which contains bean names and corresponding objects (like a command or form, containing reference data).' - Its the way to transfer objects to the view (or back) if you have to collect entries from forms, display something (dao objects) etc.

---- example
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
 model.addObject(path);
 model.addObject("user",user);
 model.addObject("greeting",service.getMessage());

return model;

// ViewName, User Bean, MSG Bean

// Spring doc

public interface Controller {

```
/**
 * Process the request and return a ModelAndView object which the DispatcherServlet
 * will render.
 */
ModelAndView handleRequest(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ModelAndView is a holder for both Model and View in the web MVC framework. Note that these are entirely distinct. This class merely holds both to make it possible for a controller to return both model and view in a single return value.

It represents a model and view returned by a handler, to be resolved by a Dispatcher. The view can take the form of a String view name which will need to be resolved by a ViewResolver object;

alternatively a view object can be specified directly. The model is a Map, allowing the use of multiple objects keyed by name.